# Express Properly define post route methods

Tags: html, node.js, express, post, routes

I am getting a routing error from using express.js with node on an application I'm working on. I am failing to get post requests to properly be handled and receiving a http 500 error here is my server.js file code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator());
var router = express.Router();
app.use(router);


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var methodOverride = require('method-override');
app.use(methodOverride(function (req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        var method = req.body._method;
        delete req.body._method;
        return method
    }
}));

var flash = require('express-flash');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(cookieParser('csci3308'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'csci3308',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 60000}
}));
app.use(flash());



var login = require('./routes/login');
var success =  require('./routes/success');
var profileCreation = require('./routes/profileCreation');
var calendar = require('./routes/calendar');
var student = require('./routes/student');
var professor = require('./routes/professor');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', login);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/success', success);
app.use('/profileCreation', profileCreation);
app.use('/calendar', calendar);
app.use('/student', student);
app.use('/professor', professor);




//error handling
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.url)
  console.log(req.method)
  console.log(req.params)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) =>{
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})


var port = 4000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:' + port)
});
```

HEre is my profileCreation.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
router.use(expressValidator());
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');
var db = require('../database.js');



router.post('/profileCreation', function(request, response){
  console.log("made it to profileCreation post route")
  response.redirect('/login')
  //request.assert('email', 'email is required').notEmpty();
  // request.assert('pswd', 'password is required').notEmpty();
  // request.assert('cfmPswd', 'confirm password is required').notEmpty();
  // request.assert('pswd', 'password and confirm password are not the same').equals('cfmPswd');
  // var queryCheckEmailNotTaken = 'select (email) from users where(email = $1)';
  // if(db.oneOrNone(queryCheckEmailNotTaken, 'email')=== null){
  //   //make eroor message
  //   request.flash('error', 'Creation failed');
  //   response.render('profileCreation');
  // }
  // else{
  //   var isProf = document.getElementById("isProfessor").checked;
  //   //var dbQueryAddUserString = 'Insert into users(email, pswd, isProffessor) values(request.sanitize('email'), request.sanitize('pswd'), isProf;
  //   var dbQueryAddUserString = 'Insert into users(email, pswdID, isProffessor) values($1, $2, $3)';
  //   db.none(dbQueryAddUserString, [email,pswd, isProf]).then(
  //       response.render('login')
  //       ).catch(function(error){
  //           request.flash('error', 'Creation failed');
  //           response.render('profileCreation');
  //       })
  //   }
});




router.get('/', function (request, response) {
   console.log('Made it to profile creation root route');
   response.render('profileCreation', {data: {}});
});

router.get('/profileCreation', function(request, response){
    console.log('Made it to profileCreation route');
    response.render('profileCreation');
});


module.exports = router;
```

And here is my profileCreation.ejs code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/profileCreation.css" type=text/css>

    <title>Profile Creation Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="wrapper" id="rootContainer">

      <div class="container" id="outerBoxContainer">

        <div class="container" id="contentContainer">

          <div class="container" id="titleContainer">

            <div class="row justify-content-center" id="titleRow">
              <h1 id="loginHeader">DayBook Profile Creation</h1>
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="container" id="profileContainer">
          <form method="post" action="/profileCreation">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwrd">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pswd" id="passwrd" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cfmPasswrd">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cfmPswd" id="cfmPasswrd" placeholder="Confirm Password">
              </div>


            <!-- <div class="radio">
              <label>Role</label>
              <br>
              <label style="font-weight:normal"><input type="radio">Student</label>
              <br>
              <label style="font-weight:normal"><input type="radio">Professor</label>
              <br>
            </div> -->



            <button type="submit" name="createProfileButton" >Create Profile</button>


            </form>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting a 500 error when I try to use my submit button on the profile creation route. I do not know what the issue is. It is like the router is not properly defining the route to handle post requests. I am using the same formula as I have for my login functionality but it is not working for some reason. The local server says it cannot post to the route. Please help me. I appreciate any feedback. I am an amateur at this stuff and think it might just be a small mistake somewhere. Thank you in advance!

Comment: won't the form action be `/profileCreation/profileCreation`? because you are using app.use so the prefix is `/profileCreation` now again you are defining a route. can you try making the action `/profileCreation/profileCreation` .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to access using

**BASE_URL + 'profileCreation/profileCreation'**

**Note:** Replace BASE_URL with your actual base URL